# jQuery-Validation-Engine not working with jQuery 2.0.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I was using jQuery-Validation-Engine and it was working greatly with earlier versions of jQuery but when i update jquery 1.7 with 2.0.3 its not working anymore.

Can anyone guide how I can configure it with jQuery 2.0.3

Regards

Comment: any errors in the browser console

Comment: No error in the browser, but form is submitted without validation.

Comment: What browser are you using because jQuery 2 and up doesn't support IE 8 and older

Comment: I am using FireFox 24.0